# Knockout foreach not clearing previous entries on new VM

Tags: knockout.js

I have a modal form with two nested lists bound to observable arrays.

Each time I click the button to open the modal, these two nested lists aren't clearing their previous data, even through I generate a brand new viewmodel for the whole thing.  I wind up with duplicated (and triplicated, etc...) items in these two lists.

How can I ensure that when I give this thing a new viewmodel, it clears out the previous data?

The ViewModel itself is fine: I can `ko.toJS(self)` that on each instance and everything's correct in the data.  It's some sort of leftover from the bindings.

Here's my bindings for that particular area:

```
<div class="notes-container" data-bind="visible: showNotesContainer">

    <label>Notes</label>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: noteGroups" class="question-list">                                
        <li>
            <span class="he-question-group" data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <ul class="he-question-list" data-bind="foreach: notes">
                <li><span data-bind="text: question"></span></li>
                <li><input type="text" data-bind="value: answer" /></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my "base" VM:

```
function hoursEntryVM(model) {

    var self = this;

    ...
    self.noteGroups = ko.observableArray(getNoteGroupsVMs(model.NoteGroups));
    ...

    var root = document.getElementById(model.rootElementId);
    ko.cleanNode(root)
    ko.applyBindings(self, root);

    return self;

    function getNoteGroupsVMs(noteGroupModel) {
        var notes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < noteGroupModel.length; i++) {
            notes.push(new hoursNoteGroupVM(noteGroupModel[i]));
        }
        return notes;
    }       
}
```

On the button click for opening the modal I have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mysource',
    success: function(data) {
        data.rootElementId = 'hours-entry-container';
        var vm = new window.myProj.hoursEntry.hoursEntryVM(data);
        console.log(ko.toJS(vm));
        myModal.Show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Never call `applyBinding` (or `cleanNode`) *inside* your view-model code. The view-model should only represent data and behavior, not to apply itself onto document. Ideally, you need something like this: `var vm = new hoursEntryVM();` then `ko.applyBindings(vm)`

Comment: @haim770 - thanks, noted.

Comment: The cleanNode/foreach issue is a known bug. The developer's suggestion is to never reapply bindings and instead wrap your view model in an observable. (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/271#issuecomment-3839897) Then you could wrap your template/page in a "with" binding that would update when you update the observable with a new instance of the view model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you figured out the best way to handle this (use templates) yourself, but you stated you'd like to know what was happening:

### `foreach` under the hood

`foreach` works like an in-place template binding. The `innerHTML` of the element bound with `foreach` is treated as a template string.

### What `cleanNode` does *not* do

When you `cleanNode`, knockout does not "undo" its bindings; it only removes the dependencies between view (HTML) and viewmodel (js). The binding context is deleted.

This means that, after `cleanNode`, the inner HTML that is used as a template changes.

### A demonstration:

```js
var source = [1, 2, 3];


var applyAndClean = function() {
  var el = document.querySelector("ul");

  console.log("Applying bindings using template:");
  console.log(el.innerHTML);

  ko.applyBindings(source, el);
  ko.cleanNode(el);
}

ko.applyBindings({
  onClick: applyAndClean
}, document.querySelector("button"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: onClick">apply and clean</button>

<ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Press the button to apply bindings and clean after. The console logs the template used. The first run, the template contains *one* `<li>` that gets repeated *three* times. The second run, the template contains *three* `<li>` elements which get repeated three times. I.e.: the number of list items equals `3^n` for `n = numer of times bindings are applied`.

### The difference with the `template` binding

The template binding doesn't care what's in the data-bound element. It simply discards all `innerHTML` and replaced it with the template linked.

Again, like the commenter stated, you should never need to call `cleanNode` (outside of, maybe, a custom binding).

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish the desired behavior using a knockout [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html):

```
<div class="notes-container" data-bind="visible: showNotesContainer">
    <label>Notes</label>

    <ul class="question-list" data-bind="template: { name: 'hours-noteGroups-template', foreach: noteGroups }"></ul>

    <script type="text/html" id="hours-noteGroups-template">
        <li><span class="he-question-group" data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <ul id="he-notes-list" class="he-question-list" data-bind="foreach: notes">
                <li><span data-bind="text: question"></span></li>
                <li><input type="text" data-bind="value: answer" /></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </script>

</div>
```

I'd still be curious to learn why the initial attempt acted the way it did though.