# How to bind a model when I don't have it at document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to bind a model on jQuery button click event which should open a modal window with a collection of array items displayed. The first time it runs the collection is correct, however on subsequent opens, the collection gets bigger each time. It doesn't seem to be creating a new array.

If I reapply the bindings I get the 'cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element' error. I have tried 'cleanNode() which doesn't clear out the array items. I cannot applyBindings() to outside the click event as I don't know the model as it is retrieved via an API service on the same click event.

HTML

```
<div class="btn" id="click1">CLICK ME 1</div>

<div id="app_test1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div data-bind="foreach: list">
          <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: cancel"><i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {

  $('#click1').click(function() {

    var data = [ {name: "Bob"}, {name: "Joe"}, {name: "John"} ];
    var viewModel = runModalTest(data);

    var el = document.getElementById('app_test1');

    ko.cleanNode(el);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, el);

    $('#app_test1').show();

  });

  function runModalTest(data) {
    var viewModel = {
      list: ko.observableArray(data),
      cancel: function () {
        $('#app_test1').hide();
      }
    };

    return viewModel;
  };

});
```

Also available on CodePen:- https://codepen.io/asteropesystems/pen/ymBXPa

```js
$(function() {

  $('#click1').click(function() {

    var data = [{
      name: "Bob"
    }, {
      name: "Joe"
    }, {
      name: "John"
    }];
    var viewModel = runModalTest(data);

    var el = document.getElementById('app_test1');

    ko.cleanNode(el);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, el);

    $('#app_test1').show();

  });

  function runModalTest(data) {
    var viewModel = {
      list: ko.observableArray(data),
      cancel: function() {
        $('#app_test1').hide();
      }
    };

    return viewModel;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn" id="click1">CLICK ME 1</div>

<div id="app_test1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div data-bind="foreach: list">
          <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: cancel"><i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I require it to display the 3 items in the array each time the modal opens.

Comment: It seems you've already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854058/knockout-model-bindings-not-clearing-when-new-model-created

Comment: Try to rewrite your code to use the `click` and `visible` bindings first. Mixing too much jQuery and knockout is usually not the way to go.

Comment: Yes @Bludev, I reworked my real world code which I cannot post only for the same issue to re appear. I broke it down to an even simpler example to try and work out the issue. It seems I broke it down too much and removed the template, hence the same issue coming back.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out by using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072018/knockout-foreach-not-clearing-previous-entries-on-new-vm). Basically by using a template in place of the raw HTML.

HTML

```
<div class="btn" id="click1">CLICK ME 1</div>

<div id="app_test1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'list-template', foreach: list }">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: cancel"><i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="list-template">
  <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</script>
```